# Red indicator for an empty queue

Tags: support, bug, review, top-bar

First of all, I apologize for posting a screenshot from Stack Overflow in Russian. If you have the same situation, you can place English version here.

My low quality queue is empty (zero items), but popup menu for low quality posts queue has red lamp.

> [image: Zero red]

Before removing counter from popup I have seen `0` and never clicked on the item with zero count. Now I see red - going in and here is nothing to review.

**Is it behavior by (new) design or some kind of bug?**

A [similar situation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5978/176217) happened for close vote queue for another user, described on ruSO.meta. He has more items skipped during review, but lamp is red and queue is empty like in my case.

As [mentioned by Möoz in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301576/red-indicator-for-an-empty-queue#comment988380_301576), this has happened on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: The logic probably hasn't changed. The dropdown shows the items available for everyone on the site, so it is not personalized. When you visit /review you get a more personalized queue count. Or we call it caching. Either way: status-bydesign.

Comment: @rene as far as I know, in old-design counts in popup reflects personal value. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I believe you're wrong. At least that is what I have always understood from several discussions with Shog9, last one was [around here in the transcript](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6120590#6120590) where we ventured into alternatives for review notifications

Comment: @rene: Always remember the difference between "always displayed on every page load" (the topbar and tag page indicators) and "AJAX loaded on demand". The latter, which is definitively what the old *and* new review dropdowns use, has no such performance problems and has been user-specific, just like loading /review, because it has almost exactly the same performance profile.

Comment: may be there are entries before. But when you opened the Q, the items were cleared but the LED were not changed

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks for explaining that. I obviously misinterpret what Shog9 explained.

Comment: [I see the same thing for 'Low quality posts'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pwy7.jpg) over at [scifi.se]. [Note that the queue is actually empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amrF6.jpg) and when I click through, there's nothing to review.